# How to generalize a method

Tags: c#

I have a method which I want to generalize. I want to use following Deserialize function for any object type, as belew:

```
ExportDefinition _expDefinition = new ExportDefinition("a.ini");
DeliveryDefinition _delDefinition = new DeliveryDefinition("b.ini");

ExportDefinition expDef = Deserialize(_expDefinition);
DeliveryDefinition devDef = Deserialize(_delDefinition);
```

```
public SomeType Deserialize(SomeType?? tp)  // What should I use instead of SomeType?
{     
    try
    {
        FileStream readFileStream = new FileStream(definitionFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        XmlSerializer serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(tp));
        tp loadedObj = (tp)serializerObj.Deserialize(readFileStream);
        readFileStream.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
     }

     return loadedObj;
}
```

Any ideas, how to achieve this?

Comment: use a generic method: `public T Deserialize<T>(T tp)` But how can the Input be of the same class as the deserialized object? doesn't make sence, does it?

Answer (score 6):

Use generics:

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(string filePath)
    {
        Stream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            XmlSerializer serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            return (T)serializerObj.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The non-generic version based on the useful comment of Marc Gravell:

```
public object Deserialize(string filePath, Type type)
{
    Stream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        XmlSerializer serializerObj = new XmlSerializer(type);

        return serializerObj.Deserialize(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Put something useful here
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are a good approach here, but just for completeness: taking a parameter of `Type type`, and returning `object` achieves most of the same, and can be preferable in some cases (where the type isn't hard coded). But in many cases the type *can* be hard-coded (at the caller), so generics work great.

Comment: is there a need for the parameter tp?

Comment: Jes you give the Type paramter and the Insance of it an that is what you want to serilize, without the insance, what do you trying to Save?

Comment: @Venson this is deserialize, not serialize; the type parameter can be specified by the caller via generic syntax. There is *one* use-case for sneaky extra unused parameters with generics - for generic type inference for use with anonymous types - but that shouldn't apply here. So I'd say "no, there is no need for `tp`"

Comment: @Venson but it should DEserialize - there you dont need an instance, but the serialized counterpart.

Comment: the instance of the Type is not used within the method. notice that the answer has been edited and the tp parameter removed.

Comment: another thing, is the local variable "stream" being used here?

Comment: @MarcGravell good point, I edited and added a version without generics.

Comment: @All: The solution works good with argument T tp as used before. I have tried without tp argument, it gives an error "method 'DeliveryFunc.Core.XMLData.Deserialize<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly".

Comment: @mrd Why do you need `tp`? You only want the type of `tp`. In the generic example, you get the type with `typeof(T)`. In the second, you specify the type as a parameter. `tp` is not used at all, actually.

Comment: @ken2k: Thats right. But, if I do not specify type argument it gives the above error. I donot know why. Can someone explain why I get this error?